# How to select records from database table which has to user id (created_by_user, given_to_user) and replace users id by usernames?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

This is task table:

[image: task table in a database]

This is user table:

[image: user table in a database]

I want to select user tasks.
I would give from backend ("given_to_user) id.
But The thing is I want that SELECTED data would have usernames instead of Id which is (created_by_user and given_to_user).

SELECTED table would look like this.
Example:

[image: example data that I need to select]

How to achieve what I want? 
Or maybe I designed poorly my tables that It is difficult to select data I need? :) 
task table has to id values that are foreign keys to user table.
I tried many thinks but couldn't get desired result.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`. What have your tried?

Comment: I Tried INNER JOIN but couldn't achieve desired result, also tried to nested select statements. But the thing is I need to select username from user table 2 times, because task table has two user id, one for a user who created that task and another ID for user who was given that task.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep. Make your post self-contained.  Please read & act on [mcve]. See [ask] & show what you tried. PS Join the table with info with the table with names then select the columns you want & not the columns you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not design poorly the tables. 
In fact this is common practice to store the ids that reference columns in other tables.
 You just need to learn to implement joins:

```
SELECT 
  task.id, task.title, task.information, user.usename AS created_by, user2.usename AS given_to
FROM 
  (task INNER JOIN user ON task.created_by_user = user.id) 
  INNER JOIN user AS user2 ON task.created_by_user = user2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want two joins?

```
select t.*, uc.username as created_by_username,
       ug.username as given_to_username
from task t left join
     users uc
     on t.created_by_user = uc.id left join
     users ug
     on t.given_to_user = ug.id;
```

This uses `left join` in case one of the user ids is missing.